# Magento 2.2 Configurable Product with Downloadable Option: Email doesn't include download links

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.2

I have a configurable product with a downloadable option. When I perform a test purchase of the downloadable product option, the confirmation email doesn't include a link to the download, but instead just shows which option was selected.

Does anyone know how I can setup Magento 2.2 to send out the necessary links? I'm learning more about the Magento platform, but there's still a lot I don't understand and I need some help getting pointed in the right direction.

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm prepared to write a custom module if that's what it takes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: The solution most likely involves programming, but I agree, this would be a good question for magento.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The solution might, but the question must for it to be on-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Going to answer my own question. I wrote a module, which can be found here (in case anyone else can benefit from it): https://github.com/crankycyclops/Crankycyclops_ConfigurableProduct